# vb database connection gives no information as to whether connection was successful

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to connect to an access database THROUGH CODE.  I capitalized that last bit because I am well aware of the visual method of doing it but can't use that method in this instance.  Basically I just want to create a databinding to a combobox on a single column from a table Title that displays the column Year.  To clear that up I want to populate cboYearsFillBy with the data from the column YearPublished.  The thing I am finding to be the biggest pain is that vb doesn't throw any sort of fuss when the db isn't found so I don't even know if it is finding it.  My code is below

```
  Imports System.Data.OleDb

    Public Class frmTitle
    ' Create untyped dataTables
    Dim dtYears As New DataTable

    ' Declare a variable to represent the DataAdapter
    Dim daYears As OleDbDataAdapter
    ' Create BindingSource objects for Employee & Dept tables:
    Dim WithEvents bsYears As New BindingSource

    Private Sub frmTitle_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim connStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\VisualStudioProjects\Biblio.accdb"
        MessageBox.Show(connStr)
        Dim titleSQLStr As String = "SELECT * FROM Title"
        daYears = New OleDbDataAdapter(titleSQLStr, connStr)
        Dim commandBuilder As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(daYears)
        daYears.Fill(dtYears)
        dtYears.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {dtYears.Columns("YearPublished")}
        bsYears.DataSource = dtYears
        cboYearsFillBy.DataSource = bsYears
        cboYearsFillBy.DisplayMember = "YearPublished"
        cboYearsFillBy.ValueMember = "YearPublished"

    End Sub
    End Class
```

I get the following output
[image: output]

Comment: Hints: Add a try/catch block and see  the exception message if any. Debug and find that dt.Years.Count to know how many rows are there. remove the dtYears.PrimaryKey, it is not required here. VB.Net would complain if the connection could not be opened.

Comment: I did try your code and it works on my machine. I use Access 2007 and have a different path that yours. I also have commented out the Primary Key statement. I suspect that your database may be in "table design mode" and this is causing the error. Again do a try/catch and display the message in the exception object.

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class frmTitle
' Create untyped dataTables
Dim dtYears As New DataTable

' Declare a variable to represent the DataAdapter
Dim daYears As OleDbDataAdapter
' Create BindingSource objects for Employee & Dept tables:
Dim WithEvents bsYears As New BindingSource

Private Sub frmTitle_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim connStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\VisualStudioProjects\Biblio.accdb; Persist Security Info=True"
    MessageBox.Show(connStr)
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection
    con = New OleDbConnection(connStr)
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
    con.Open()
    End If
    Dim titleSQLStr As String = "SELECT * FROM Title"
    daYears = New OleDbDataAdapter(titleSQLStr, connStr)
    daYears.Fill(dtYears)
    cboYearsFillBy.DataSource = dtYears
    cboYearsFillBy.DisplayMember = "YearPublished"
    cboYearsFillBy.ValueMember = "YearPublished"
    con.Close()  
End Sub

End Class
```

I simplified your code just try now

Comment: Tried it and got the same results.  I noticed this in the output A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Comment: you misout connection property just add connection property and try I added connection property in my code

Comment: I still ended up with the same results.  Thanks though

Comment: what comes your result and send any pictures

Comment: I added it to the post

Comment: you using asp.net or vb.net and set break point in your application and check each activity that is helpful to you

Comment: I am using Vb.net.  It is a windows form application